# Passing arguments to console app with specific format c#

Tags: c#, cmd, console

I wanna pass arguments to c# console app with this specific format.
Suppose my app's exe name is SmsSender,
I wanna this format in my cmd:
SmsSender -m message -p phonenumber

How can I do this?

Comment: Please show us your attempt so far.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this Microsoft Docs [How to Display arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/main-and-command-args/how-to-display-command-line-arguments)

So in your case in you console app in your Main method you will have something like this:

```
class CommandLine
{
     static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // The Length property provides the number of array elements.
        Console.WriteLine($"parameter count = {args.Length}");
        // Get values using the `args` array in your case you will have:
        // args[0] = "-m";
        // args[1] = "message";
        // args[2] = "-p";
        // args[3] = "phonenumber";

        for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Arg[{i}] = [{args[i]}]");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You just write that command into a command prompt window, exactly as you have written in there

Inside your c# app you have a `static void Main(string[] args)` and the args array will have 4 elements:

```
args[0] = "-m";
args[1] = "message";
args[2] = "-p";
args[3] = "phonenumber";
```

But be aware that if you don't wrap your message in "quotes" (in the command prompt) then every word in the message will be a different entry in args